# How RTCPeerconnection object will send UDP Packet to TURN Server?

Tags: webrtc, turn

I want to know which medium will it use either sockets/ http/https?

```
yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration, { optional: [{ RtpDataChannels: true }] });
```

Comment: Did you read the docs properly? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection

Comment: Yes, Creating Offer, Handling Offer, Sending ICE Candidate through WebSockets but once direct connection was failed then RTCPeerconnection object will send a request to STUN Server to get the Public IP once it receives the IP then It will send ICE Candidate info will be exchanged b/w clients then both will try to establish a connection  if it was also failed then RTCPeerconnection object will send UDP Packet to TURN Server

Comment: and then TURN server will act as Intermediate server so here my query is which protocol (i.e, wss,https,TURN Protocol) will be used by RTCPeerconnection object to communicate STUN/TURN servers